# How to sum array values by defined keys?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

```
$array[0] = 100;
$array[1] = 10;
$array[2] = 15;
```

How can I get sum of array by its keys like `key = (0,1)` so the `sum = 110` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
$array = array(
  0 => 100,
  1 => 10,
  2 => 15
);
$keys  = array(0, 1);
$sum   = 0;

foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
  $sum += $array[$key];
}
```

Comment: @DainisAbols As far as I can see it should work as expected. What are your concerns?

Answer (score 3):

The best and simple way is

```
$result = array_sum($your_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$sum = array_sum(
    array_intersect_key($array, array_flip([0,1])
);
```

Didn't test it, but should work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array[0] = 100;
$array[1] = 10;


$array[2] = 15;

$sum = function($keys = array(),$arrayList= array())  {
        $s = 0;
        foreach ($arrayList as $key => $value) {
           if(in_array($key, $keys)) {
               $s+= $value;
            }
        }
        echo $s;
};
$sum(array(0,1),$array);
```

Comment: Just curious: Why do you use an anonymous function here? As far as I can see you can completely omit it, rename some variable names (`$container` (bad name anyway ;)) => `$array` to iterate over and `$key` must be set) and at the end simply `echo $s`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$array[0] = 100;
$array[1] = 10;
$array[2] = 15;

echo array_sum($array);
```

OR try this

```
$array[0] = 100;
$array[1] = 10;
$array[2] = 15;
$sum=0;
foreach (range(0,1) as $key)
{
    $sum = $sum+$array[$key];
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to sum Arrays by defined keys:

```php
$myArray=Array("Array Title","1000",2000,3000}; // array example with stings and integers

var_dump(array_intersect_key($myArray, array_flip(Array(1,2)))); // int(3000)
var_dump($myArray); // int(6000)
```

References:

[array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/function.array-intersect-key.php)

[array_flip](http://php.net/manual/function.array-flip.php)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to sum intial two keys then use below code:

```
array_sum(array_slice($array,0,2)); // will return 110
```

References:

[`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

[`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Answer (score -2):

```
$count = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
 $count = $count + $array[$i];
}

echo $count;
```